# Run devenv from commandline

Tags: .net, command-line, devenv

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lRet&
    lRet = Shell("cmd /k devenv m:\myproject.sln /build Release", 1)

End Sub
```

This fails with the command line saying "devenv" is misspelt or not found.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Is it on the `%PATH%` environment variable?

Comment: What do you mean, please?

Comment: You can find path to devenv from registry using command `reg query`.

Comment: Look at file `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` for details.

Comment: Usually, path to devenv is not your %path% varialbe. So, cmd just does not know where to look for devenv.exe

Comment: I am using VS2010. I have also tried the following         MsgBox(File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"))

        Dim lRet&
        lRet = Shell("cmd /k C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe m:\myproject.sln /build Release", 1) but then the command line tells me that "c:\Program" was not found. Argh...

Comment: @Validmir Frolov Do you mean the environment variable "Path"? If yes, I have added the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\" to the environment variable "Path", but the command line still does not find it.

Comment: "cmd /k \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe\" m:\myproject.sln /build Release"

Comment: Path with spaces should be surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran all "bat" files that I could find in the VC programs directory. 
First I started them not as as admin, and it did not work.
When I started the bats as an admin, the command would finally work.
Also I had to move to the VS path using CD.