# " 'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command ..."

Tags: visual-studio, command-prompt, devenv

Is there a way to just open a VS project from the command prompt? For example, the way with Atom, you can navigate to the folder you'd like to open and just run "`atom .`" Does that kind of utility exist for VS?

**edit**: Would the equivalent to this be "`C:\> devenv /run SomeSolution.sln`" ?

if so, great! But there still seems to be a problem because I think the "devenv" command should at least be recognized, but I currently get

> 'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I saw that a S/O contributer [recommended adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704230/run-devenv-from-commandline)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

to the PATH environment variables values like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx), per MSDN, which I did, but I get the same message.

Can anyone explain what might be going on and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Use the Start menu to launch the Visual Studio command prompt (whatever version of VS you're using), in some versions called the Developer Command Window. From that prompt, `devenv` should work. You can't add an executable to the PATH; you can add the folder that executable is located, though. Nothing in the question (including answers or comments) recommending adding what you said to the PATH, however.

Answer (score 37):

You need to **add** new path to existing **Path** value.

## Complete solution:

1. Go to `MyComputer >> Properties >> Change Settings >> Advanced >> Environmental variables`
2. Click on **Path** value on bottom pane, and then click **Edit**.
3. Add new path to your devenv.exe **folder** location.
   *For me this is `"D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022\Common7\IDE\"`*

EDIT: Updated path to Visual Studio 2022

Comment: for me, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE`

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE

Answer (score 5):

On similar issue, for VS 2017, I wanted to build a solution, below worked fine:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" Project.sln /build
```

Answer (score 4):

This is much easier than it looks. Go to the root directory for the project, type the name of the `.sln` file, and hit Enter. Windows knows how to use the registry o find `devenv.exe` based on the extension of the file you run.

For example:

```
cd \Projects\SampleApp
SampleApp.sln
```

This technique is the same as if you opened the sln file by double clicking it in Explorer.

Comment: how to run this as well

Answer (score 1):

**VS 2019 Community**

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

**Any Visual Studio Version**

To find your specific devenv.exe path regardless of VS copy/version you can use **cmd** and then run:

`cd \`

`dir /s divenv.exe`

**Note**: The command `dir /s` may take a few minutes to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had no desire to update my PATH variable, I used the following steps to run `devenv` on the command prompt:

1. Navigate to the Visual Studio shortcut on the Start menu
2. Right-click the shortcut
3. Click on properties
4. Copy the path displayed in Target. This is the path to whatever version of `devenv` that you use.
5. Paste the copied path into the command prompt and press enter

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a windows machine, and for this command to work, **devenv** must be added to the path environment variable.

First ensure you have visual studio is installed on your machine.

On my machine, the **devenv exe** is available at the following location.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE

Next add this to the path environment variable.

Open System Properties

[image: Windws System Properties]

[image: Path Env Variable]

Do not forget to close your command prompt and then start it again. This will enable the env vars to load into the command prompt.